# What is the intuitive notion of an isotopy?

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry

I'm studying introduction to topology. The book is trying to give an intuitive notion of an homeomorphism and isotopy. As I understand it an homeomorphism is the continous function ( with continous inverse ) that represents the "deformation" of one topological space ( such as a bottle ) into another ( an squeezed bottle ). What is an isotopy then? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Think about how you would untie a knot $K$. Starting at time $t=0$ and ending at time $t=1$, you continuously move pieces of it around inside 3-dimensional space, and do so in a non-impossible way (e.g. the knot can't move through itself).

Now the knot remains "the same" at each moment in time - "$K_{t_1}$" and "$K_{t_2}$" are homeomorphic for any times $t_1, t_2$. But this isn't really the main feature of "untying a knot" - rather, we care about *how it moves through the ambient space*.

This is the idea behind isotopy. We think of $K$ as an abstract space, and $K_0$ and $K_1$ as the images of two separate *embeddings* of $K$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$; and the fact that $K_0$ can be deformed into $K_1$ in a "nice" way means that there is an *isotopy* between these two embeddings (namely the *process* of deforming the knot).

(EDIT: actually, this is misleading - unknotting knots is a *really* nice process, and is better thought of as an example of *ambient* isotopy. General isotopies allow you to do weirder (but still reasonably "tame") things (see Andreas' comment below).)

---

There are then many special kinds of isotopy - ambient isotopy, smooth isotopy (in the context of differential geometry), etc. - but this should give the general picture.

Comment: Concerning knots and the importance of ambient isotopy, see my comment on the answer from arctic tern.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Good point, I didn't mean to be misleading; fixed!

Answer (score 0):

While a homeomorphism 'connects' two topological spaces, an isotopy 'connects' two embeddings (maps) between topological spaces, so they concern different type of objects.